# Проблемы с установкой RxJS

Tags: javascript, html, rxjs

Создал index.html и script.js, подключил, установил RxJS  с помощью

```
npm install rxjs
```

Но при попытке импортировать Observables

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

в консоли выскакивает такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Принятый ответ ошибочен и вреден. На самом деле, **ошибка возникает из-за попытки подключить к странице исходник (а не собранный бандл).** ESM в браузере работают не так, как при использовании сборщика. В частности, здесь проблема в пути источника импорта, и использовании js вместо mjs. Короче говоря, используемый тобой синтаксис импорта - именно для сборщика, а не для браузера. Значит надо собирать.

Comment: yar85 , что тогда нужно использовать для браузера?

Comment: @yar85 , консоль пишет, что, при попытке использовать of - Uncaught ReferenceError: of is not defined

Comment: Для браузера - нужно использовать mjs (вместо js) c `type="module"`, и относительные/абсолютные пути к файлам в импортах (вместо имени пакета). Браузер ведь ничего не знает о пакетах... Но вообще, лучше не париться с ESM в браузере - и просто собрать код любым сборщиком.

Comment: Где можно посмотреть, как это поэтапно происходит?

Comment: Не понял... Посмотреть на что именно? Если на процесс сборки, то в консоли можно)) Конечно же, после того как установишь сборщик и введешь команду `npm run build`.

Comment: Установка сборщика тоже одной командой (если структура папок уже правильная, для простой сборки настраивать ничего не требуется). Гайд по **webpack**: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/ **Rollup** - еще проще (хотя он менее популярен): https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по всему вам нужно добавить в index.html тэг

```
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

тогда у вас будет доступна переменная rxjs.
подробней смотрите здесь:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs#cdn

подчеркиваю, что не нужно пытаться импортировать rxjs подобным образом:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

переменная rxjs уже будет доступна.
попробуйте создать html файл со следующим содержанием, откройте его в браузере и посмотрите в консоль.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const { range } = rxjs;
        const { map, filter } = rxjs.operators;

        range(1, 200).pipe(
        filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
        map(x => x + x)
        ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пробовал -  не помогло

Comment: дополнил описание

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо! Вы были правы, импортировать не нужно было